# Is there a difference between array and array[:] in Go?

Tags: go

[boltdb/bolt](https://github.com/boltdb/bolt) is an embedded key/value database for Go.

When I read the source code of bolt, I find the following code,

```golang
p := db.pageInBuffer(buf[:], pgid(i))
```

from: https://github.com/boltdb/bolt/blob/master/db.go#L350

But I can not get the reason why it use `buf[:]` instead of `buf`, can anyone provide an explanation for this code style?

Comment: Normally, if `buf` is an array, `buf[:]` is a slice on that array. However, in this case, `buf` appears to be a slice, so `buf[:]` returns the identical slice, so there doesn't seem to be a functional difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. yeah, there is difference when we talk about array and slice.